# How do I create JTextFields on a popup when I select JRadioButton in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java Swing.

When I select a JRadioButton it should pop up with JTextFields where the user can enter details like name, age, etc. Please let me know if anything is wrong.

Can anyone help me out for the below sample code?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class DialogTest extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private static final String TITLE = "Season Test";

    private enum Season {
        WINTER("Winter"), SPRING("Spring");
        private JRadioButton button;
        private Season(String title) {
            this.button = new JRadioButton(title);
        }
    }

    private DialogTest(JFrame frame, String title) {
        super(frame, title);
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
        radioPanel.setSize(800,800);
        radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        for (Season s : Season.values()) {
            group.add(s.button);
            radioPanel.add(s.button);
            s.button.addActionListener(this);
        }
        Season.SPRING.button.setSelected(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(radioPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JRadioButton b = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose: " + b.getText());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DialogTest(null, TITLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please add them to the question.

Comment: I am not getting any errors... I am unable to create popup with JTextFields...

Comment: Change `showMessageDialog` to `showInputDialog`?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you want a "modal" dialog.  See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

You could also use a `CardLayout` to reveal more details when the button selection changes, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details